# string_dec and string in Ocaml library

Tags: ocaml, coq, coq-extraction

I have file:

- `String0.ml` extracted from `String.v` (It is from Coq library)
- `String.ml` : is a string library of Ocaml

After extracted my test file from Coq to Ocaml, I want to used `String.ml` in the library of Ocaml, so I write an replace command to replace all `String0` to `String`.

The problem is in the file `test.v`, I used one of the definition:

```
Definition beq_string := beq_dec string_dec.
```

function `string_dec` is not occur in the library of Ocaml, but it has in the string library of Coq

So I have an error when I compile `test.ml`

```
open String
let beq_string = beq_dec string_dec
```

**Error: Unbound value string_dec**

I want to used the string library of Ocaml for all my extraction files. How can I able to compile `string_dec` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the `string_dec` function as well.

If you're willing to trust the OCaml library a little, you'll get a lot better performance by extracting `beq_string` to use the built-in equality on strings:

```
Extract Constant beq_string => "((=) : string->string->bool)".
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a MyString.ml module containing :

```
module String0 = struct
  include String
  let string_dec = function ... (* the definition of string_dec *)
end
```

and in all your files generated by Coq, start by

```
open MyString
```

Then, you don't need to rename `String0` into `String`, and it will use the functions defined in the String module, plus the `string_dec` function that you have defined.